# Bijective correspondence between normal vector fields and n-forms

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-forms, vector-fields

Let $M$ be an $n$-dimensional smooth submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$. I'm having trouble convincing myself that, as one might intuit, there is a bijective correspondence between smooth normal vector fields on $M$ and elements of $\Omega^n(M)$. Let's say that the map is 
$$Y\mapsto\omega_Y$$
where $Y$ is a normal vector field and $(\omega_Y)_p(W_1,...,W_n) := $det$(Y(p),W_1,...,W_n)$. This is injective, and it would be surjective if we could find a nowhere-vanishing normal vector field $Y$, for then one could use the fact that $\omega_{fY}=f\omega_Y$ to get any element of $\Omega^n(M)$. But how does one get such a $Y$?

Comment: Do you mean $k=  n+1$?

Comment: Yes you're right. I've modified my question to reflect that.

Comment: "How does one get such a $Y$" The existence of a nowhere-vanishing normal vector field is equivalent to the hypersurface being orientable. This is not always true.

Comment: Instead, for the reverse map, let $\{e_1, \ldots, e_{n+1}\}$ be the standard basis vectors of $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$, and consider the mapping $$ \omega\mapsto e_1 \omega(e_2, \ldots, e_{n+1}) + e_2 \omega(e_3, \ldots, e_{n+1}, e_1) + \cdots + e_{n+1} \omega(e_1, \ldots, e_n) $$ Check that this is injective and gives a normal vector field.

Comment: Does $\omega$ act on vectors in $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ by projecting down to $TM$ first (so that it takes vectors in the normal bundle to $0$)? Also, how do you verify that this vector field is normal? Thanks.

Comment: (1) yes, project. (2) Let $\pi$ be the orthogonal projection in $T\mathbb{R}^{n+1}|M$ to $TM$ and note that $$\pi (e_1 \omega(\cdots) + \cdots + e_{n+1} \omega(\cdots)) = \pi( e_1 \wedge \cdots \wedge e_{n+1}) : \omega $$ where $:$ means full contraction along the last $n$ slots. Now $\pi(e_1\wedge \cdots \wedge e_{n+1})$ is an alternating $(n+1)$-vector over an $n$ dimensional vector space, and so is zero.

Comment: I guess one way to see that $\omega\mapsto e_1\omega(e_2,...,e_{n+1})+...+e_{n+1}\omega(e_1,...,e_n)$ is injective is by extending it to a form on a tubular neighbourhood $\subseteq\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$, and then one knows what the $n$-forms look like on this Euclidean space. Still not sure about why it's normal...